# Positive lookbehind in grep extracting table names from sql files

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to extract table names from a large set of SQL files. The pattern is simple enough, any word following FROM or JOIN with white space.

Sample input would be something like:

```
SELECT t1.a,t1.b,t2.c,t2.d,t2.e
FROM TABLE1 t1
JOIN TABLE2 t2 on t1.a = t2.b
```

I have a .NET regex pattern that does what I want but I can't seem to translate it to a grep pattern.

```
(?<=FROM\s|JOIN\s)\w+
```

Any suggestions on how to do this with grep?

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression is correct, you just need the `-P` flag:

```
$ echo 'SELECT t1.a,t1.b,t2.c,t2.d,t2.e
FROM TABLE1 t1
JOIN TABLE2 t2 on t1.a = t2.b' | grep -Po '(?<=FROM\s|JOIN\s)\w+'
TABLE1
TABLE2
```

Comment: Updated the answer.